# Chef - Option 'subscribes' doesn't work properly

Tags: logging, chef-infra

Hello everyone who wants to help.

Recently I discovered I have a little problem.
I want to add some logging to my chef in this specific manner

```
log name do
    message             information
    action              :nothing
    level               :info
    subscribes          :write, "#{type}[#{name}]", :immediately
 end
```

My goal is to create new recipe (log.rb), where I will put all my log with "subscribes" option bounded to resource I want to log.

My problem is fact, that it doesn't work. Cookbook will compile, but no logs will be displayed - if I change action to ':write', all logs are displayed, but not when I want to (subscribes doesn't work, so it all just show like a normal recipe).

Whats weird, only resources "powershell_script" work properly

```
powershell_script 'Run repo script' do
    code <<-EOH
         Start-Process "cmd.exe"  "/c #{node['template']['path']['repo']}"
     EOH
end
```

but this wont log any info

```
template 'JBoss instance settings' do
    source          node['template']['jboss_server_setting']
    path            node['template']['path']['jboss_server_setting']
end
```

Do somebody have an idea, why it doesn't work f.e. with template, cookbook_file and remote_directory?

My Chef is 12.4.1, i am running chef-client in local mode. Operating system: Microsoft Windows 7. Please, ask for additional info.

Here are some debug infos:

**a) for powershell_script**

```
Line 16223: [2015-07-31T09:05:39+02:00] INFO: Processing log[Run repo script] action nothing (line 7)
Line 16224: [2015-07-31T09:05:39+02:00] DEBUG: Skipping log[Run repo script] due to action :nothing
Line 16225: [2015-07-31T09:05:39+02:00] INFO: Processing powershell_script[Run repo script] action run (line 23)
Line 16227: [2015-07-31T09:05:39+02:00] DEBUG: Provider for action run on resource powershell_script[Run repo script] is Chef::Provider::PowershellScript
Line 16295: [2015-07-31T09:05:40+02:00] INFO: powershell_script[Run repo script] ran successfully
Line 16296: [2015-07-31T09:05:40+02:00] INFO: powershell_script[Run repo script] sending write action to log[Run repo script] (immediate)
Line 16296: [2015-07-31T09:05:40+02:00] INFO: powershell_script[Run repo script] sending write action to log[Run repo script] (immediate)
Line 16297: [2015-07-31T09:05:40+02:00] INFO: Processing log[Run repo script] action write (line 7)
```

**b) for another resource**

```
Line 16170: [2015-07-31T09:05:38+02:00] INFO: Processing log[JBoss instance settings] action nothing (line 7)
Line 16171: [2015-07-31T09:05:38+02:00] DEBUG: Skipping log[JBoss instance settings] due to action :nothing
Line 16172: [2015-07-31T09:05:38+02:00] INFO: Processing template[JBoss instance settings] action create (line 66)
Line 16174: [2015-07-31T09:05:38+02:00] DEBUG: Provider for action create on resource template[JBoss instance settings] is Chef::Provider::Template
Line 16175: [2015-07-31T09:05:38+02:00] DEBUG: template[JBoss instance settings] checksumming file at C:/Projekty/Colis/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/servers.xml.
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: `subscribes`' first parameter is the value of the `action` attribute of the resource to which your log resource subscribes. it's expecting to see a `write` action from the resources it subscribes to. in this case you could probably remove the `subscribes` switch this to have a unique resource name like `log my_log do ...` and in your other resources, add a `notifies` attribute instead.

Comment: @Derek yes, I have considered this way, but it isn't so good like subscribes option - you have to put logging logic to other recipes (and with subscribes you would only have it in one file - adding a log info wouldn't force you to edit another rb).

Comment: Could it be because the powershell_script is always updated_by_last_action but template can be or not, and during your tests it is not?